# SQL Server 2012: filtering resultsets before fulltext search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

We have a SQL Server 2012 table defined like so:

```
create table Files (
    id int identity(1,1),
    folderId int not null,
    fileName nvarchar(256),
    [...],
    constraint PK_Files primary key nonclustered (id)
)
```

We have a fulltext catalog with an index on Files.fileName. Searching works ok, except we'd like to allow users to fulltext search for files inside a specific folder. This should be super fast: any specific folder would only have a fraction of the number of files in the entire Files table.

Alas, it seems that the query returns all the rows matching our fileName fulltext search first, and only then filters them by folderId. For example, searching for

```
select * from Files where contains(fileName, 'file*') and folderId = 5
```

returns 75,000 rows for the fulltext search, and then filters them down using folderId to 9 rows. It takes 19 seconds to run. The entire folder only has about 285 files, so doing the fulltext search against just those 285 files would be much better.

How would one go about doing that?